# How to remove spray-can/1.3.3 from response

Tags: scala, spray, spray-can

I use `spray.io` to serve HTTP requests. In response there is information about spray framework that I would like to remove. So how to remove `"Server: spray-can/1.3.3"` from the response header in `spray`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set this via `application.conf`:

```
spray.can {

  server {
    # The value of the `Server` header to produce.
    # Set to the empty string to disable rendering of the server header.
    server-header = spray-can/${spray.version}
  }
}
```